# Socket.close() not closing on serverside

Tags: python, sockets, pygame

My group and i had made a Wifi-rover on Raspberry Pi with Python and pygame (school project). We got everything to work. However, there is a tiny problem. When closing pygame, the client keeps spamming the server. The connection closes on the client, but you have to do it manually on the server.

Raspberry Pi:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-

#moduler vi importerer for at kunne bruge pins, LED og socket
from gpiozero import LED
from gpiozero import PWMLED
from time import sleep
import socket
import sys, termios, tty, os

# Setup ports, vi definerer hvilke pins på Ras der anvendes, samt binder dem til variabler

mIn1 = LED(26)
mIn2 = LED(16)
mEn1 = PWMLED(12)
mIn3 = LED(20)
mIn4 = LED(21)
mEn2 = PWMLED(13)



# Global variables - denne starter på 0.0
left = 0.0
right = 0.0

# Function for controlling left motor - her definerer vi hvornår hvilke LED's skal være on og off for at fortælle om den skal køre eller ej
def leftmotor(lspeed):
    if lspeed < 0 :
        mIn1.on()
        mIn2.off()
        mEn1.value = abs(lspeed)
    else :
        mIn1.off()
        mIn2.on()
        mEn1.value = lspeed

# Function for controlling right motor- her definerer vi hvornår hvilke LED's skal være on og off for at fortælle om den skal køre eller ej
def rightmotor(rspeed):
    if rspeed < 0 :
        mIn3.on()
        mIn4.off()
        mEn2.value = abs(rspeed)
    else :
        mIn3.off()
        mIn4.on()
        mEn2.value = rspeed

antalForbindelse = True

# her defineres socket'en - altså vi fortæller at den skal oprette socket og lave variabel der hedder skt
skt = socket.socket()

# host er ip adresse på server (raspberry) port er den port både klient og server lytter på, skal være den samme
HOST = '127.0.0.1'  # Standard loopback interface address (localhost)
PORT = 7000        # Port to listen on (non-privileged ports are > 1023)

# Bind binder host og porten som skal lyttes på - skt.listen fortæller vores server at den skal lytte efter indkommende "pakker"
skt.bind((HOST,PORT))
skt.listen()

# Linie 63 til 65 laver et print hvor den fortæller hvilken IP adresse der er connected og at den ER connected
#Linie 66 til 68 Den fortæller hvilke taster der er trykket på i pygame på clienten og dekoder den inkommende data til bogstaver igen (sendt som bits)
while antalForbindelse:
  forbind, addr = skt.accept()
  print('The client with IP: ', addr, ' has connected')
  while True:
    data = forbind.recv(1024)
    dekodet_data = data.decode('UTF-8')                 
    if dekodet_data =='a':
        left=left +0.1
        leftmotor(left)
        print(left)
    if dekodet_data =='s':
        left=left -0.1
        leftmotor(left)
        print(left)
    if dekodet_data =='f':
        right=right -0.1
        rightmotor(right)
        print(right)
    if dekodet_data =='d':
        right=right +0.1
        rightmotor(right)
        print(right)
    if dekodet_data =='w':
        right = 0.5
        left = 0.5
        rightmotor(right)
        leftmotor(left)
                    
    print('Received', repr(data))
#den nederste linie her fortæller i pygame hvilke tryk der tastes mens server og client kører
```

Client:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
#moduler vi importerer for at kunne bruge pins, LED og socket
import socket
import pygame

# Laver et display (300, 200) definerer størrelsen og display der viser hvilke tastetryk der trykkes ned i pygame
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((300,200))
pygame.display.set_caption("Tema 2")
gameLoop = True
print("Kører klienten\n")

# her defineres socket'en - altså vi fortæller at den skal oprette socket og lave variabel der hedder skt
skt = socket.socket()

# host er ip adresse på server (raspberry) port er den port både klient og server lytter på, skal være den samme
HOST = '192.168.111.179'  # IP adressen på raspberry pi
PORT = 7000        # Porten den lytter på

# Sender connect anmodningen til server som så svarer at der gerne må deles/sendes data, samt den fortæller hvilken host og port der skal sendes handshake til
skt.connect((HOST,PORT))

#Det burde sende at hvis vi trykker på krydset så skal spillet afsluttes
while gameLoop:
    # Tjek for events (hændelser)
    events = pygame.event.get()
    for event in events:
        # Hvis vi trykker på det røde kryds i højre hjørne, afsluttes spillet
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            gameLoop = False
            skt.close()

#Importerer tastatur tryk fra pygame og encoder dataen til at blive sendt til serveren (på server decodes der og det bliver igen til tastetryk)

        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN  and event.key == pygame.K_a:
            msgFromClient = "a"
            indkodet_data = msgFromClient.encode("UTF-8")
            skt.sendall(indkodet_data)
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN  and event.key == pygame.K_s:
            msgFromClient = "s"
            indkodet_data = msgFromClient.encode("UTF-8")
            skt.sendall(indkodet_data)
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == pygame.K_d:
            msgFromClient = "d"
            indkodet_data = msgFromClient.encode("UTF-8")
            skt.sendall(indkodet_data)
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == pygame.K_f:
            msgFromClient = "f"
            indkodet_data = msgFromClient.encode("UTF-8")
            skt.sendall(indkodet_data)
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == pygame.K_b:
            msgFromClient = "b"
            indkodet_data = msgFromClient.encode("UTF-8")
            skt.sendall(indkodet_data)
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == pygame.K_w:
            msgFromClient = "w"
            indkodet_data = msgFromClient.encode("UTF-8")
            skt.sendall(indkodet_data)


         #Hvis ikke der bliver tastet en defineret tast men istedet andet tastetryk en asdfwb så printes der ingenting
        else:
            msgFromClient = ""
skt.close() # Lukker forbindelsen

print("Socketen blev lukket")
```

I apoligize in advance if this is a bad asked question

Comment: please post a minimal reproducible example, not pastebin links that will most likely expire soon.

Comment: I've set them not to expire

Comment: you are supposed to create a question with [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) within the question, not on some offsite source, see second step - _Complete – Provide all parts someone else needs to reproduce your problem in the_ **question itself**

Comment: Considering I'm not Danish, I have no idea what those comments or many of the variables means. I'd suggest you rewrite the question to English. I see many problems in your code that's going to cause lots of issues, but since many of those lines are commented, I'll assume it explains why the code is that way and that the problems are accounted for.

Comment: @TedKleinBergman that's correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The server won't shut down because you never tell it to. If the server would shut down whenever a client closed, then it wouldn't be possible to have multiple clients connected.

The `recv` method will return the message the clients sent, or 0 if the client has closed the connection. So simply check for it and shutdown the server when that happens.

Comment: So adding a skt.close() to the buttom of server.py?

Comment: No, your server is a process, i.e. a stand-alone program. You need to check `if data == 0:` and then do whatever is necessary to close the program. A simple `if data == 0: exit()` might suffice.

Comment: Or I don't know what "skt" is, since that seems to be a variable only present in your client script. If it's your server socket, then yes, do that, but that will only close the socket. My assumption is that you want to shut down the server, not just the connection, right? If yes, do what I said in the comment above; if no, do what you said.

Comment: Your assumption is right. I want the server to say something like "The socket has closed" when closing pygame

Comment: @Techguy So did the post answer your question? In that case, feel free to mark it as answered. Otherwise, feel free to explain what's missing so I can edit more information in.

Comment: Oh, sorry about that. Marked it as an answer :-)